# How to get parameter from reference

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm using firebase for my application. I also using firebase cloud functions. My question is,how can i get a parameter from the reference (please see the picture) into *const commentid*
 [image]

Comment: When showing code on Stack Overflow, don't use images.  You should copy it into the question, formatted as code, so it's easier to read and search.

Answer (score 1):

You're coding to an old version of the firebase-functions module.  Since version 1.0, the onWrite handler takes two arguments - a Change object and an event context.  [Please see the documentation for more details](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events).

```
exports.commentsCount = functions.database.ref('/comments/{commentId}/{userId}').onWrite((change, context) => {
    const commentId = context.params.commentId
})
```

You will also have to adapt your code to use the new change object instead of the old event object.